# Runtime permission: shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale always returns false

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Below is my code, i called this code for getting runtime permission. In this case the "shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale always returns false". I cannot find a solution why it is goind like this. Due to this the run time permission alert not displayed. Suggest me a solution pls...

```
   private void checkRuntimePermission() {

    Logger.infoLog("checkRuntimePermission");
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Logger.infoLog("checkRuntimePermission first if");
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WelcomeActivity.this,permissionsRequired[0])){
            Logger.infoLog("checkRuntimePermission if");
            //just request the permission
            //Show Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera and Location permissions.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeActivity.this,permissionsRequired,PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }else{
            Logger.infoLog("Show request permission rationale false");
        }
    } else {
        //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
        Logger.infoLog("Permission given already");
        proceedAfterPermission();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

in google docs:

> "This method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request."

so, you should invoke **requestPermissions(...)** first, then use  **shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...)** can get the result that you want.

The best method is that always using **requestPermissions(...)** in **onRequestPermissionsResult(...)**

Answer (score -1):

The method you are invoking is asking the question "should we show the reason for requesting this permission?"

From the Docs `"This method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request."`  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

If that value is false, you still want to request the permission but you don't need to show the alert dialog.  So, in the else block just simply

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeActivity.this,permissionsRequired,PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
```